# Check if multiple (more than two) arrays match, regardless of element order in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

If I have two arrays `a` and `b`. I can compare them as `a.uniq.sort == b.uniq.sort`. This will tell me if the elements in `a` match those in `b`.

What if I have four arrays `a, b, c, d`? I need to make sure they are all equal to each other. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[%w[a b c], %w[c b a], %w[a a b c], %w[b a b c]]
.group_by{|a| a.uniq.sort}.one? # => true

[%w[a b c], %w[c b a], %w[a a b c], %w[b a b c d]]
.group_by{|a| a.uniq.sort}.one? # => false
```

Comment: Nice one! I had the feeling `group_by` would bring to a clean solution but I missed it!

Answer (score 3):

Take one array, sort it's unique elements and compare the other arrays with that as reference. Return false as soon as one is not equal.

```
ars = [a,b,c,d]
ref = ars.pop.uniq.sort #take care: pop mutates ars
p ars.all?{|ar| ar.uniq.sort == ref}
```

Comment: Yes, or `ars.map(?:sort).uniq.size == 1`, though this doesn't have the short-circuit property that yours has.

Comment: You can use `ars[0]`, `ars[1..-1]` in order to leave the original array of arrays untouched.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that doesn't involve sorting.

Let `arr` be an array of the given arrays. If the arrays contained no duplicates, this would be simple:

```
first, *rest = arr
rest.all? { |a| (first-a).empty? && (a-first).empty? }
```

To deal with duplicates, we define a helper `Array#difference`:

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end
```

In a nutshell, if `n` elements of an array `a` equal a given object and `m` elements of an array `b` equal the same object, the array `a.difference(b)` will contain (the first) `[n-m,0].max` elements of `a` that equal the object .

Then we can write the following.

```
first, *rest = arr
rest.all? { |a| first.difference(a).empty? && a.difference(first).empty? }
```

The block evaluates `true` if every element of `a` maps to a unique element of `first`, and vice-versa.

It may seem a waste of time to create `Array#difference` for just this one problem. I have found, however, it to be a valuable member of my tool kit, having  wide application, so much so that I proposed it [be added to the Ruby core](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815). The link gives examples of its uses and also contains a link to an SO answer I gave that contains a longer list of problems where it has found application.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice `reduce` solution:

```
ars.reduce { |a, v| a.uniq.sort == v.uniq.sort ? v.uniq.sort : break }
```

Which ends up to pretty clean code used in conjunction with `map`:

```
ars.map { |v| v.uniq.sort }.reduce { |a, v| a == v ? v : break }
```

The *map -> reduce* version is not the the best for performance since all the array elements get `uniq.sort`'d, but it's readable and functional style.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use uniq you can use intersection, without the uniq intersection couldn't be used to compare arrays.

```
arr.inject(:&).sort == arr.first.uniq.sort
```

This would mean that arrays like

```
[3,2,3,1]
[1,3,2]
[3,2,1]
[2,1,3,1]
```

would be the same

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
a.uniq.sort == b.uniq.sort and b.uniq.sort == c.uniq.sort and c.uniq.sort == d.uniq.sort
```

To optimise it, you can store the result of `b.uniq.sort` and `c.uniq.sort` in some variable to prevent repeated computation before comparing.

Comment: That is not scalable... What if there are 10 arrays? or 15?

Comment: Edited the answer to consider this